# Error: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point in Edge

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, runtime-error

[Here is the HTML markup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Kjm1.png)I have tests passing on my local machine everytime and fails on the VM used in the Azure devops pipeline everytime with this error:
Here is code i have used:

```
        {
            string xpath = "//*[text() ='" + text + "']";
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
            driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement();
            IWebElement element = driver.WaitAndFindElement(By.XPath(xpath));
            wait.Until(condition => element.IsDisplayed() && element.Enabled);
            driver.WaitAndFindElement(By.XPath(xpath));
            element.Click();
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        }
```

These are the things I have done:

1. Maximizing the window when i select the browser edge
2. added explicit waits
3. even using WaitAndFindElement method.
4. Even added switch to active element even though there is no popups here.

Here is the WaitAndFindElement method

```
        {
            DefaultWait<IWebDriver> wait = new DefaultWait<IWebDriver>(driver);
            wait.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds);
            wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250);
            wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException));
            IWebElement element = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    IWebElement elem = d.FindElement(by);
                    if (!elem.Displayed)
                        return null;
                    return elem;
                }
                catch (NoSuchElementException)
                { return null; }
                catch (NoSuchFrameException)
                { return null; }
            });

            return driver.FindElement(by);
        }
```

I have tried all the solutions given in various posts and it keeps failing in the devops pipeline used VM. When I log in to the VM during the tests are running, it succeeds.
Can someone please guide me how to fix this issue?

Here is the HTML markup as asked:

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium , I was not able to paste the html since it was huge. so i attached the html screenshot

Comment: You don't need to paste a huge html but only the relevant part of the HTML>

Answer (score 0):

We were able to fix the issue. It was resolution problem on the VM. So we created a task in devops pipeline to increase the resolution before starting the tests. Now all the tests are passing on VM too. Thank you for coming forward to help me.

Answer (score 0):

This error may mean two things:

- element is overlapped in example by loading screen;
- element is not in viewport and You need to scroll to find it.

You should add scrolling logic to search for element that needs to be clicked. Even if You changed resolution on testing host and now it works there are chances that in the future error will appear again and You will want to click something in example in table that needs to be scrolled to.

Comment: Yes, I changed resolution on my local machine and found that I needed scrolling the page to find the element. I was able to fix it by adding a if loop to check if its able to find the element, if not, then scroll the page and find the element. Yes after adding the logic its working everytime. Thanks for all the help